# CSS hover: last type of child display:none; display:block;

Tags: html, css, hover

Hello guys i'm strugling with an hover element  i build a #nav bar with few elements inside the last  element (Logout) contains 2 pictures i try to change the picture after mouse(hover) over how can i manage it.

HTML

```
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#Stuff1">Stuff1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Stuff2">Stuff2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Stuff3">Stuff3</a></li>
      <li><a href="?logout=1">Logout<img id="on" src="img/on.png" alt="button"/><img id ="off" src="img/off.png" alt="button"/></a>
      </li>
```

CSS

```
#nav ul img
{
vertical-align: middle;
padding-left: 5px;
}

#nav
{  
max-width: 100%;
border: 2px solid white;
color: green;
background-color: grey;    
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#nav_wrapper
{
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

#nav ul
{
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
position: relative; 
list-style-type: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#nav li 
{

    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover
{
    background-color: #333;
}

#nav ul li a,visited
{
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#off
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way

```
/* default state */
ul li:last-child img {
   display: block;
}   
ul li:last-child img + img {
   display: none;
}

/* switch images display on :hover */
ul li:last-child:hover img {
   display: none;
}   
ul li:last-child:hover img + img {
   display: block;
}
```

Note: since in your example there are images only on a single list-item, you can simplify the rules, omitting both `ul` and `:last-child` so as to decrease their specificity and make the example working even on IE8 (`:last-child` [doesn't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) in that browser)

Comment: i would prefer to see a class used here as to avoid any potential headaches should the nav order ever change in the future.

Comment: @halabuda good catch, but he could even avoid a class and just use `[href^="?"] img` and `[href^="?"] img + img`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan you still run into the same problem should the link ever change. adding a class to the list element would be persistent.